# JBoss Fuse 6.x to run PAX-EXAM itests with JDK 1.8

Tags: jbossfuse, pax-exam

Seems like artifacts of JBoss Fuse 6.2.x and 6.3.x compiled with JDK 1.7 and PAX-EXAM itests work fine, though they error out with JDK 1.8.

Same applies if you create own OSGI bundle and use Maven dependency:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1.redhat-084</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

So if you want you project build with JDK 1.8 you have to exclude PAX-EXAM itests from maven lifecycle and run another process with JDK 1.7 just for itests.

Moreover JDK 1.7 end of life as of April, 2015 - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

---

$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

$ cd D:\projects\jboss-fuse-6.2.1-621084-sources\camel-2.15.1.redhat-621084\tests\camel-itest-osgi

$ mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=false

---- **ERRORS** ----

ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement: org.osgi.framework.startlevel;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.0", org.osgi.framework.wiring;uses:="org.osgi.resource,org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.hooks.service;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver;uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring";version="1.0", org.osgi.framework.launch;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.namespace;uses:="org.osgi.resource";version="1.0", org.osgi.framework;version="1.7",org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving;uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring";version="1.0",org.osgi.resource;version="1.0",org.osgi.service.url;version="1.0",org.osgi.service.startlevel;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1",org.osgi.service.packageadmin;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.2",org.osgi.service.url;version="1.0", org.osgi.util.tracker;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.5.1", org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot;version="2.4.0.redhat-621084", org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal;version="2.4.0.redhat-621084", org.apache.karaf.management.boot;version="2.4.0.redhat-621084", org.apache.karaf.version;version="2.4.0.redhat-621084", org.apache.karaf.diagnostic.core;version="2.4.0.redhat-621084", ,org.apache.karaf.branding, org.apache.html.dom; version="2.11.0", org.apache.wml.dom; version="2.11.0", org.apache.wml; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.parsers; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.models; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xni.parser; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.util; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.dom3.as; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath.regex; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xni; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.msg; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.util; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.util; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.dom; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.dom.events; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xs; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.io; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xpointer; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xinclude; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xs.datatypes; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.identity; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.models; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xni.grammars; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.validation; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xml.serialize; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xalan.extensions; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.compiler; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.cmdline.getopt; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.util; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.transformer; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.processor; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.lib; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.trace; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.compiler.util; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.templates; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.xsltc; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.runtime; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.xslt; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.lib.sql; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.runtime.output; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.dom; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.client; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.cmdline; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.serialize; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xalan.res; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xml.dtm; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.sax2dtm; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.dom2dtm; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xml.res; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xml.serializer; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xml.serializer.utils; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xml.utils.res; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xml.utils; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xpath.functions; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xpath.jaxp; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xpath.patterns; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xpath.objects; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xpath.res; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xpath; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xpath.axes; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xpath.compiler; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xpath.operations; version="2.7.2", org.apache.xpath.domapi; version="2.7.2", sun.misc (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(ManifestParser.java:768)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.(ManifestParser.java:214)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.(ExtensionManager.java:229)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.(Felix.java:388)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory.newFramework(FrameworkFactory.java:28)
        at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:343)
        at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.main(Main.java:561)
ERROR: Bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn [1] Error starting file:/D:/projects/jboss-fuse-6.2.1-621084-sources/camel-2.15.1.redhat-621084/tests/camel-itest-osgi/target/paxexam/unpack/47c6e70d-0ca7-48e4-9e4d-99337bc51e10/system/org/ops4j/pax/url/pax-url-aether/2.4.2/pax-url-aether-2.4.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn [1]: Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.6.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers)])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn [1]: Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.6.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers)]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4002)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR: Bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap [2] Error starting mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-wrap/2.4.2//uber (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap [2]: Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.naming))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap [2]: Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.naming)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4002)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR: Bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [3] Error starting mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/1.8.4 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [3]: Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [3]: Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4002)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR: Bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service [4] Error starting mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-service/1.8.4 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service [4]: Unable to resolve 4.0: missing requirement [4.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service [4]: Unable to resolve 4.0: missing requirement [4.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4002)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.felix.configadmin [5] Error starting mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.configadmin/1.8.4 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.felix.configadmin [5]: Unable to resolve 5.0: missing requirement [5.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.felix.configadmin [5]: Unable to resolve 5.0: missing requirement [5.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4002)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.felix.fileinstall [6]: Unable to resolve 6.0: missing requirement [6.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.6.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.felix.fileinstall [6] Error starting mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.fileinstall/3.5.0 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.felix.fileinstall [6]: Unable to resolve 6.0: missing requirement [6.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.6.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4002)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.karaf.features.core [7] Error starting mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.core/2.4.0.redhat-621084 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.karaf.features.core [7]: Unable to resolve 7.0: missing requirement [7.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace))org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.karaf.features.core [7]: Unable to resolve 7.0: missing requirement [7.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace)

```
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4002)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you provide a log of the errors?

Comment: [errors.zip - complete maven log](https://mega.nz/#!z5IkQYoI!UZJekBx0IYbFmw2GIZ6i8Cb55NiYa-efMzey7Sr6CTo)